# Hide select option Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

Isn't there any way to do it?

I have made [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapas_23571113/h5wHD/) which is not working in IE.

The piece of code is given below:

The HTML

```
<select id="testing">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#testing option').eq(1).attr({
        disabled: 'disabled'
    });
});
```

The CSS

```
select option[disabled] {display: none;}
```

Any pointer would be helpful.

Note: I cannot use `.remove()` method.

Comment: which IE version is targeted?

Comment: From my experience, IE does not accept styling on `<option>`, I don't think there is actually a solution.

Comment: Try using prop() instead of attr() http://api.jquery.com/prop/ like this $('select#testing option').eq(1).prop("disabled", true );

Answer (score 0):

Try `select option[disabled=disabled]` or alternatively set a class `disabled` on the `option` elements to which you apply the CSS rule (`display: none;`).

**EDIT**

After testing this on IE9 I discovered that it does not let you hide the option element, at least not via `display:none;`, setting `disabled="disabled"` does disable the element, but not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

To support IE7 you will have to resort to some hacks, see this post [Disable Select Options in Internet Explorer](http://harrybailey.com/2008/11/disabling-select-options-in-internet-explorer/) .